# Are the nodes of Greek mythology a major concept?

Tags: greek, concepts

The Wikipedia article for the Calydonian Boar says that

> Like the quest for the Golden Fleece (Argonautica) or the Trojan War that took place the following generation, the Calydonian Hunt is one of the nodes in which much Greek myth comes together.

There is no reference on this claim, and I was wondering what scholastic work has been done on the "nodes" of Greek mythology (presumably defined as the episodes during which many heroes of a generation come together). Is this a major concept in the study of mythology?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word "node" is not (as far as I know) used in the study of literature/folklore/mythology. What I think the Wikipedia article is trying to refer to is the idea that the Calydonian Boar story features a gathering of many *characters* in Greek mythology come together.

The academic word for this concept would probably be an [epic catalogue](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/q/545/62). The phrase epic catalogue refers to the poetic device of making really long lists of things, e.g. a list of characters. I talk a little bit more about epic catalogues in the Stack Exchange question I linked to above.